# API for seeing who opened particular document in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api

Does anyone know any API where I can collect the information on who opened particular documents in Google Drive and what time the documents were opened?

Comment: This is a fair question. I think.

Comment: But I only see API retrieving changes. Could you show me how to know who just viewed the document?

Comment: I don't think there can be an API other than the one Google provides. If that API doesn't have this information, it's not available. You should submit an enhancement request to Google.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, if no more answers later on, I'll submit the enhancement request.